# Why wont my restrictions work for the if statement because it still prints NA when i specifically told it not to let NA go through

Tags: python

[image: data table]

My condition of `if row[2] != 'NA'` is not working, it's still letting my NA go through??

```
import numpy as np

def microcar(expected, actual):
    with open ('actual2.csv', 'r') as inputfile:
        actual2_contents = inputfile.readlines()


    for row in actual2_contents:
        row = row.split(',')
        print(actual2_contents)

        if row[2] != 'NA':
            x = row[2]
            print(x)
            x = float(row[2])
            print(x)
            print(type(x))


        else:
            row[2] = -1 # i want to replace the N/A with the number -1 but this wont work either
```

attatched an image of the output [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20eYU.png)

Comment: Hi, are you able to post the contents of the CSV file you are reading?

Comment: Are you sure that there is no white space around NA? Please add the contents of the entire row to your question.

Comment: Unrelated, but get rid of `actual2_contents` and just iterate over `inputfile` directly. (Even better, use the `csv` module to parse the file instead of `row.split(',')`).

Comment: @LucyBrown: change to `row = row.strip().split(',')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `item[2]` is read as `NA\n` and your condition checks it's `NA` or not.
Try this:

```
if row[2] != 'NA\n':
            x = row[2]
            print(x)
            x = float(row[2])
            print(x)
            print(type(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should strip your string of whitespaces.

```
ifString = row[2].strip()
```